# Devise Rememberable not working after Chrome/Firefox browser applications closed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, firefox, devise, warden

In a `Rails 4.2` application, I have `Devise` installed on an application with the `Rememberable` and `Timeoutable` modules activated.

When a user logs in, chooses `Remember Me`, and closes the browser **tab**, their login is retained when they open up a new **tab** and return to the application. This is consistent with Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

However, when a user logs in, chooses `Remember Me` and closes the browser **app**, they are logged out of the application when they re-open the browser **app** and open a new browser tab. This is consistent with Chrome and Firefox. Safari, on the other hand, works as desired.

Is it possible to retain the user login credentials when a user closes the Chrome and Firefox browser **apps**? I suspect this is a cookie issue, but I don't know what settings I need to change to keep the cookie valid between browser **app** closings.

The behavior is consistent between Windows and Mac platforms.

### Configurations

#### Chrome

```
Settings > Content settings > Cookies > Allow local data to be set = selected
```

#### Server

- Rails 4.2
- Devise 3.4.1

#### Client 1

- Mac OSX 10.10.2 (Yosemite)
- Chrome 41.0.2272.101 (64-bit)
- Firefox 36.0.4
- Safari 8.0.4 (10600.4.10.7)

#### Client 2

- Windows 7
- Chrome  41.0.2272.101 m
- Firefox 36.0.4

#### User Model

```
# models/user.rb

devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :registerable, :trackable, :validatable, :async, :timeoutable
```

#### Devise Config

```
# note: User model does have remember_created_at field installed

# config/initializers/devise.rb

Devise.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.remember_for = 2.weeks
  config.extend_remember_period = true
  config.rememberable_options = { secure: true }
  config.timeout_in = 2.weeks
  config.expire_auth_token_on_timeout = false
  ...
end
```

Comment: Are you using default devise sign in view? Also, does your model have remember_created_at attribute?

Comment: Yes, on both points. I suspect that's why the browser tab closing works. Just not sure on the browser app closing.

Comment: check if secure_compare is failing

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb how?

Comment: @wrburgess managed to solve this?

Comment: @wrburgess It would be great if you could provide some follow up on this for other people that might be experiencing the same problem.  Even just a "never figured this out" would be better than nothing.

Comment: Never figured it out

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me and the workaround is by adding the `expire_after` manually into `config\initializers\session_store.rb`.

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_app_session', expire_after: 2.years
end
```

Note: replace `_my_app_session` with your cookie name that you can check on your browser while opening your page in production or staging `right click > inspect > application > cookies`